# How to get all data when add new item in array ? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using angular Material to show data in Angular table. 
I have all crud operation. All work good except when I add new Item-Product i am need to refresh to see it. That is problem. 
I have two component.
Item LIST
Item ADD
Item List show list and add button for add.
Item ADD is modal dialog angular material and here i set my logic for add item.
My question. 
How to live show data when add new item without to refresh page?
Remeber my add logic is on different component.
My code: 
List:

```
  <mat-table [dataSource]="ItemDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- item Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="item_id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Item id. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.item_id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Item name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="item_name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  > Item name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.item_name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Ts:

```
  getItem() {
    this.item.getAllItem().subscribe(data => {
      this.allItem= data;
      this.ItemDataSource.data = this.allItem;
    })
  }
```

my ADD component:

```
........logic form noting important
```

ts:

```
  getCountry() {
    this.items.AllITems().subscribe(data => { 
      console.log(data); // ALL ITEMS return
    })
  }


  onSubmit() {
    this.item.addNewItem(this.item.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.notify.showSuccessAlert();
          this.Item();
          // I AM TRY TO CALL ALL ITEM BUT THIS IS NO WORK HERE..
        },
        err => {
          this.notify.showErrorAlert(err);
        });
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz?

Comment: After getting all the items again, try setting the datasource data again like you did in the beginning. `this.ItemDataSource.data = this.allItem;`. Not sure what you mean to say you were calling since you just wrote `this.Item()`. The table won't register a change if you just push items on to the dataSource array.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

In your **Item ADD dialog** you must be having an *Add* button, add `[mat-dialog-close]` to it:

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
```

Afterwards, you must be calling **Item ADD dialog** from **Item LIST**, add `afterClosed()` to it and check:

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result){
      // Call getAllItems() here
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your getItem() method as a callback function in your onSubmit() method as shown below. This should refresh your items once you add a new one.

```
onSubmit() {
        this.item.addNewItem(this.item.value)
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.getItem();
            },
            err => {
              this.notify.showErrorAlert(err);
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

### - I think this help to get some idea to your question.

***I have added the stackblitz demo also***

## .html

```
    <form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(checkoutForm)">
  <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="lbl">
      <label>Enter here</label>
          <input formControlName="EnterHere" required>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button (click)="getvalue()">Submit</button>
      <button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div><br><br><br><br>You entered:
   <div *ngFor="let data of data" class="jsonData">
     {{data|json}}
    </div>
</form>
```

## .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  checkoutForm;
  data : any = [];

constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
  ) { 
      this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'EnterHere': ['', Validators.required],
      });
   }


  getvalue(){
    this.data.push(this.checkoutForm.value);
      console.log(this.data);
  }
  clear(){
   this.data = [];
 }
}
```

- I used a array to display when you enter something in your text box without refresh!
- And I think you can use **eventEmiter** to emit your data one component to another

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-array-values)